# Rails. Reverse polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand reverse polymorphic associations in Rails.
I followed [this guide](https://gist.github.com/runemadsen/1242485), but i got an error. When I write `some_type_object.clubs` it works pretty well, but when I try to `some_club_object.type` i get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :type_elements in model Club
```

How to fix it?

Here is my models:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :type_element, as: :element
  has_one :type, through: :type_elements
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :type_element, as: :element
  has_one :type, through: :type_elements
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :type_elements
  has_many :clubs, through: :type_elements, source: :element, source_type: 'Club'
  has_many :events, through: :type_elements, source: :element, source_type: 'Event'
end

class TypeElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :element, polymorphic: true
end
```

My migrations:

```
class CreateClubs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clubs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateTypeElements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :type_elements do |t|
      t.belongs_to :type, index: true
      t.integer :element_id
      t.string :element_type

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :type_elements, :types
    add_foreign_key :type_elements, :elements
  end
end

class CreateTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :types do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :type_element, as: :element
  has_one :type, through: :type_element # <- change
end
```

I think you should be ok having Type as a class. You shouldn't have it as a field unless you really want STI.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have a migration column named `type`. It is a ruby/rails reserved word and causes trouble if you have something named that. I believe that it is also true with Model names but not 100%. Change any names from `type` to something else and those errors will disappear.

Comment: I think @evanbikes is correct. With your old code, you had `has_one :type_element, as: :element` and then `has_one :type, through: :type_elements`. Change `:type_elements` to `:type_element` and you should be good (of course, accounting your name changes).